# How to add such line in the axis

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

How could I add the lines in axis to highlight the ticks?
This is the examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwOtm.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `length` and `width` parameters in `ax.tick_params` like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
y = x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.tick_params(direction='in', length=10, width=3, color='r')
```

[image]

Additional info here https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html